# When NOT to use garbage collection?

Tags: language-agnostic, memory-management, garbage-collection

The obvious cases for not using garbage collection are hard realtime, severely limited memory, and wanting to do bit twiddling with pointers.  Are there any other, less discussed, good reasons why someone would prefer manual memory management instead of GC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It IS possible to use garbage collection with hard real time, if you have fully incremental garbage collector with bounded execution time per byte of allocated memory, so, crazily enough, it is NOT necessarily a reason not to use garbage collection :)

One fundamental problem with garbage collection, though, is that it is difficult to estimate and manage the actual size of the working set in memory, because garbage collector can free your memory only delayedly. So, yes, when memory is restricted, garbage collection might not be a good choice.

Another problem with garbage collection is that it sometimes interferes with freeing other resources such as file descriptors, window handles, etc., because, again, the garbage collector might free those resources only delayedly, causing resource starvation.

Garbage collection can also cause cache trashing, because the memory is not necessarily allocated in a local fashion. For example, stack allocated memory is much more cache-friendly than heap-allocated short-lived objects.

Finally, garbage collection of course consumes CPU time :) So if you can code manually memory management you can save the CPU cycles the garbage collector would consume :)

Comment: Re: CPU time: manual memory management *also* takes up CPU time. Modern garbage collectors have an overhead of less than 3%. I doubt even the most experienced C programmer can get significantly below 1%. There's two ways you can look at this: either a garbage collector is twice as expensive as ...

Comment: ... manual memory management, or the difference is negligible (~97% vs. ~99%).

Comment: Isn't the overhead of a garbage collector relative to the amount of "extra" memory available? By adding more memory, you need to reclaim garbage less often, making the process more effective. An old result is that if you consume 16X memory GC is MORE efficient than manual memory management.

Comment: Well, that also applies to manual memory management: if you have lots of memory, you need to free less often. Although of course the GC has a significant advantage: it can adapt its behavior to different circumstances at runtime, whereas with manual MM the programmer has to decide at design time.

Comment: Actually, it is different. With manual memory management (as long as you use e.g. new() or malloc()) you dealloc every block once, so it's O(N) where N=allocated objects. A stop-and-copy collector, say, runs in O(N) with N=size of reachable set during collection, a huge difference.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: The 3% figure you quote varies wildly from program to program and it says nothing about latency. Th statement " Although of course the GC has a significant advantage" is non-sensical because manual MM can reinvent the GC so it is a superset of GCs.

Answer (score 3):

Temporary insanity?

Actually the only case I know of that you haven't covered is so-called "lifetime-based memory management", which sometimes goes under the name "pools" or "arenas" or "regions".  The idea is that you're going to allocate a ton of objects, probably small, and *they're all going to die at once*.  So you have a cheap allocator and then you recover *all* the objects in a single free operation.

These days there are program analyses that will enable a compiler to do this for you, but if you're writing C code, you do it by hand.  There's an implementation with examples in Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/), and it's used in Fraser and Hanson's [`lcc` compiler](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/), which is written in C without a garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

When programming for embedded devices with limited resources.  iPhone, for instance, uses reference-counting.

Or when programming something that is extremely intensive on your computer.  SETI@Home and video games come to mind.

I would advise that you don't manage your own memory unless the situation dictates it's really necessary.  Somebody famous once said that code is twice as hard to debug as it is to write.  Well, memory management is hard enough in the first place. :)

Comment: Many microcomputer BASIC interpreters in the 1980s used garbage-collection for strings, and the resource constraints of a VIC-20 were just as tight as many embedded systems today.  To be sure, the GC algorithms used in many of those systems were really horrible, but some better GC functions have been published which could use the same data structures.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason NOT to use Garbage Collection for resource management is if you want to use RAII ala C++, but as it applies purely to memory, even then it's a reasonable idea to use it. (Note: It's still possible to do so, with gotcha's related to non-deterministic finalization).

That said, using Garbage Collection can use more memory than is strictly needed, so in severely memory constrained areas where one can not even spare the memory for managing the GC routines (and the code), then that's a good reason not to use it, too.

Additionally, if the language you use doesn't contain GC by default, such as C++, and you like to use RAII, then that's a reasonable reason too, though for some problems it can be very useful.

Ultimately it comes to tradeoffs - the more specialized your requirements, especially with regards to thread-safe RAII, the more complex it is to implement the GC, and GC might not buy you very much for your application.

Comment: "The only reason NOT to use Garbage Collection for resource management is if you want to use RAII ala C++". You can use both.

Comment: @JonHarrop: Agreed, this answer was two years ago, however, using a GC in C++ makes you investigate various tradeoffs... The only 'transparent' way to do this, imho, is to delegate GC only to RAM usage, ie, as a more efficient new/delete in some situations and to avoid the need to specify the 'owner' of a data structure that largely consists of pure data (ie, without non-memory resources).  If you agree, please feel free to update my answer - you certainly have enough reputation. :)

Comment: FWIW garbage collection can also be useful for external resources that are equivalent to memory. I had a lot of success using finalizers in OCaml to apply GC to geometries and textures cached on the graphics card using OpenGL display lists.

Comment: @JonHarrop: I would consider that a special case - you're still dealing with essentially plain old data, it just lives in a different RAM location.  Normally, in C++, "external resources" can mean very different things - it could be a file - or a TCP/IP connection, or a database connection - or, even, an actual machine that it's controlling.

Answer (score 1):

Emm... my professor's reason is to make our (his students') life harder and to teach us "the real thing". Haha :)

In general, though, garbage collection is not always optimized for your specific app, so if you're one good programmer, you will definitely do a better job at memory management than GC ever will.

Comment: Bad information.  Look up Ben Zorn's paper on the measured cost of conservative garbage collection.  And that's *conservative*, known to be slow compared with accurate GC.

Comment: What do I know, I'm just a 2nd-yr CS student :D

Comment: @NormanRamsey: You're citing a paper that is 19 years old and presented measurements on a 33MHz SPARC with 16MB of RAM running single-threaded programs making just 2,000 calls to `malloc` per second (because they `malloc` pools). Your assertion that convervative GC is slower than accurate GC in that context is also bogus.

Comment: @DV.: You're quite right that hand-written code can outperform production GCs. One obvious example is the write barrier that is incurred when a pointer is written into the heap. For example, sorting an array of strings in-place is much slower with almost any production-quality GC.

Comment: @jon: got science?  then cite it

Comment: @NormanRamsey: Here is a counter example where porting an *n*-queens solver written in OCaml to C/C++ and using a stack is faster than OCaml's GC. http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/boosts-sharedptr-up-to-10-slower-than.html

Comment: @NormanRamsey: Here are two more counter examples. Building a VM that allows programs to be written such that they avoid garbage collection allows a ray tracer to outperform garbage collected languages (Java, Haskell, OCaml and Standard ML) and compete with C++. The C++ itself is a counter example because none of the GC'd languages are competitively performant. http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/hlvm-on-ray-tracer-language-comparison.html

Comment: @NormanRamsey: Here is a counter example where a company called Rapid Addition use value types to do manual memory management in C# in order to evade allocation and garbage collection during steady state operation in the interests of performance. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20918

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other, less discussed, good reasons why someone would prefer manual memory management instead of GC?

Perhaps the most important unspoken issue is the code that the VM injects in order to make it work in harmony with the GC. In particular, all production-quality GCs silently incur a write barrier whenever a pointer is written into the heap.

For example, the following F# program creates an array of 10,000 ints and then exchanges them:

```
do
  let xs = Array.init 10000 int
  let timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
  for i=0 to xs.Length-2 do
    for j=i+1 to xs.Length-1 do
      let t = xs.[i]
      xs.[i] <- xs.[j]
      xs.[j] <- t
  printfn "%f" timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

Change that `int` to `string` and the program runs 2x slower because ints can be exchanged directly whereas exchanging reference types must incur two write barriers.

Another important situation that people love to brush under the rug is pathological behaviour of conventional GCs. Today, most GCs are generational which means they bump allocate into a nursery and then evacuate survivors to an older generation (typically mark-sweep). This works well when the generational hypothesis (that objects die young and old objects rarely refer to newer objects) holds because most of the objects in the nursery are dead when it is efficiently swept. But objects don't always die young and old objects are sometimes full of pointers to new objects.

In particular, the pathological behaviour of a generational GC is manifested when a program allocates a large array-based mutable data structure (e.g. hash table, hash set, stack, queue or heap) and then fills it with freshly-allocated objects. These new objects survive because they are referred to from an older object, completely violating the generational hypothesis. Consequently, solutions using GCs are typically 3x slower than necessary here.

FWIW, I believe mark-region GCs have the potential to evade these problems in the future. In a mark-region GC, the old generation is a collection of former nurseries. When a thread-local region fills and is found to contain mostly reachable objects the whole region can be logically migrated into the old generation without copying any objects and a new nursery can be allocated (or an non-full old nursery can be recycled).

Comment: One thing I've thought would be useful in an embedded GC framework would be to have a means of specifying that a particular type cannot contain nested mutable strong references (and have the framework enforce that); if one kept a list of all older-generation objects that could contain nested GC references and scanned that list on every gen0 scan, one could avoid the need for card tables, write fences, etc. when storing references.  Of course, this would only work well for usage patterns that favor mostly-immutable structures, but such things are common in many applications

Comment: Hash tables are still a problem and immutable dictionaries are *much* slower.

Comment: So, hash tables and all direct references in them would have to be scanned on each GC pass (though if the references within the table identified immutable objects they could quickly be recognized as being older-generation).  That would still be a lot cheaper than requiring *all* objects to be scanned on every GC pass, which is what I understand the .NET Micro Framework requires.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if it would be possible for .NET to define an attribute for reference-type variables or parameter such that (1) storing a reference to such a variable would set the "dirty" bit for the entire object identified by that reference, if not already done, but (2) stores made via that variable/parameter would not need to check dirty bits.  Sorting a `string[]` would thus require tagging the entire array as dirty (something that would likely end up happening anyway) but that would be done wholesale outside the sorting loop rather than piecemeal within it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ton of objects which are freed rarely the garbage collector will start and waste time just to find out that there are only a few objects to finalize. In extreme cases this may cause a huge performance penalty.

Comment: -1: "In extreme cases this may cause a huge performance penalty". I don't believe that. Can you demonstrate a >10x slowdown with a production GC or quantify your assertion.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Interesting. Do you consider only > 10x slowdown a problem?

Comment: Depends what you're doing but "huge performance penalty" means orders of magnitude to me.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: For whom how. If my system spends 20% time in *useless* garbage collection (I mean it works hard but can't collect anything) it means it has 20% time less to do useful things and that's a problem for a CPU-bound system.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: I can't continue this discussion. I already wrote *in extreme cases* in my answer, I'm pretty sure that's enough for my answer to convey the right message.

Comment: Can you quantify what you mean by "a huge performance penalty"?

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Actually that means "huge enough to bother" which can be a very wide range - sometimes you don't care if some activity takes 95% time because the whole program only takes 1% of total CPU time and sometimes 20% becomes a problem because the program is strongly CPU-bound and those 20% could be used for something useful and that's your only CPU on an embedded system, so usual "processors get faster" whining doesn't cut anymore.

Comment: Ok. Can you quantify a bound on what you mean by "a huge performance penalty"? For example, how big was the largest such slowdown you have ever observed?

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Do you mean only cases where GC was at fault?

Comment: I'd be interested in any such cases.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: One very good case I remember very well wasn't due to GC, but is a very good example. We developed a server application that would dispatch work items to worker nodes. Code for finding the next item to dispatch was written in such way that under certain conditions it would burn all the CPU time and a quad-core server would be able to fully load no more than five worker nodes. Once we eliminated that bottleneck it would easily load more than a hundred and had a fair amount of idle CPU time. That was an observable change - the whole system performance increased about 20 times.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: The moral of that case for me was: one never knows which part of code will slow the system down.

Answer (score 0):

How about for security reasons? Eg if you've got an encryption private key in memory, you'd probably want it around for the shortest possible time.

Having said that, i think the way hardware is heading, learning the art of multithreaded programming may be more worth learning.

Comment: free() doesn't wipe memory either.

Comment: Good point - you'd probably want to zero out the memory. Having said that, with immutable strings for instance in C#, it's a challenge to zero it out, because the moment you change the string, it simply creates a new string. Some tricks would be required (or you could use SecureString)

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is, "Where security / system stability is not a primary requirement".

Bear in mind that applications given free reign over memory can cause all sorts of security concerns, including that of simply allocating and not freeing memory (DoS attack by slowing system to a standstill through insufficient available memory resource). This is a core part of Java's security model, for instance -- its GC ensures this can never happen.

My view, like that of Jon Harrop, is that GC adds overheads to system performance for several reasons (noted in other answers here); it is more indirect but more secure and takes responsibility for memory management away from the application developer; but there is always a performance cost for satefy nets.

Answer (score 0):

### Garbage Collection vs Leaks

One of the primary reasons for me to avoid garbage collection is to avoid resource leaks in areas where leaking is critically bad. Garbage collection is great when safety and simplicity is your goal, but not to avoid leaky software.

**A common scenario we've encountered with GC is that it's hard to avoid resource leaks with it.**

Now this might confuse some people and seem paradoxical as to how garbage collection combined with less-than-ideal team practices can lead to leaky software, but the non-trivial management of resources in a software lie not with resources tied to a limited scope, but the persistent ones that linger around.

### Complex Resource Management

An example of such complexity is a scene graph in a 3D software with millions of lines of code and thousands of objects and classes interacting with each other through events.

In these cases, these persistent objects often store handles/references to resources in the system, perhaps other objects living in the persistent scene graph. In such scenarios, you can have a central resource, `R`, like a complex 3D model that takes hundreds of megabytes of RAM, being accessed by many different parts of the scene and the user interface. For example, both a camera and light object might store a list of references to objects to exclude from the camera view and lighting system, of which such complex 3D models could be included.

In these cases, and in a team environment, it is not too uncommon for 3 separate developers to write code that stores persistent handles/references to `R` in dozens of different places in code. When the user removes `R`, *all* of these places should release the handle/reference.

*Without* garbage collection, if one of them fail to do so (perhaps he/she was having a bad day, is one of the less experienced developers, was in a high-pressure deadline crunch with looser testing and review standards, whatever the reason), a dangling *pointer/handle/reference* is left. Accessing it will *crash* the application with a segfault. Tracing such a segfault with a debugger will often immediately reveal where and why it happened.

*With* garbage collection, nothing obvious may happen except that running the software for longer periods of time continue to leak more and more resources. Because one of these places forgot to release the reference, permanently extending its lifetime, and continue using it in a valid, non-destroyed state, the software may not only continue to rise in memory usage but also get slower and slower the longer you run it processing hidden objects that are no longer visible to users.

### To Crash or Not to Crash

In these types of cases, sometimes the obvious and glaring crash resulting from this mistake that can be immediately caught and handled during testing is actually *preferable* to a silent and very difficult-to-spot resource leak that could be a nightmare to trace down and may never be fixed.

So if you are working on such a project where an immediately obvious and correctable crash during testing might actually be preferable to a leaky software that often flies under the testing radar with such mistakes, garbage collection, unless it is combined with very careful coding standards and an awareness among every team member to watch out for its pitfalls (the need for weak or phantom references, e.g.), can actually do more harm than good. To me, garbage collection works best with much smaller, tighter teams and projects with actually a *higher*, not lower level of expertise in state/resource management, or ones where such resource leaks aren't anywhere near as bad as crashing.

From an in-the-trenches developer perspective, a glaring, in-your-face, showstopping bug is often preferable to the very subtle, hidden, *'no one knows what happened but something bad happened'* kind of bugs. It often spells the difference between your debugger telling you what happened versus blindly flailing about trying to find needles in a haystack of millions of lines of code. Managing resources in large-scale systems is one of the most difficult things to get right, and garbage collection doesn't actually make this any easier. To crash or not to crash, that is the question, and in these scenarios we're often looking at the dangling handle crash without GC or the mysterious resource leak with it. In performance-critical applications dealing with potentially enormous resources, such leaks are often unacceptable.

Answer (score -1):

When you are building high-performance apps such as first person shooter games, you don't want GC that will potentially impact your app's execution.  Manually managing the memories in those apps allow you to decide the right time to free up resources.

Comment: Look up "incremental garbage collection" and visit www.lua.org.  Look for their logo on the splash screens of your favorite games...

Comment: So lua is guaranteeing worst-case collection time now?

Comment: Your comments are misguided.  Lua is just a scripting language and it's not used in the part of a game that requires the most performance.  Show me a first person shooter game that uses a full-blown GC mechanism or Lua to implement their rendering pipeline or physics.